# Rows of Monthly Counts in Redshift - how to include 0 rows in results for months with no activity

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a query that gets a count of pageviews for each month from Redshift, but I can't get 0 rows to show up. I `right join` across a table of months but it's still failing

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
coalesce(count(*), 0) as count, 
date_trunc('month', pv_date) as month_date, 
months.month_date as joined_month_date 
FROM pageviews 
RIGHT JOIN months 
on date_trunc('month', pv_date) = months.month_date
GROUP BY month_date, joined_month_date
```

Which returns something like --

```
15 | 2020-11-01 00:00:00 | 2020-11-01 00:00:00
23 | 2020-09-01 00:00:00 | 2020-09-01 00:00:00
```

What am I missing? I want a 0 row for October 2020.

Comment: What is in the `months` table?

Answer (score 0):

I think `LEFT JOIN` is easier to follow.  You need to count a column from the `pageviews` table to get the non-matches.  And aggregate by the column in `months`:

```
SELECT count(pv.pv_date) as count, 
       m.month_date as joined_month_date 
FROM months m LEFT JOIN
     pageviews pv
     ON date_trunc('month', pv_date) = m.month_date
GROUP BY m.month_date;
```

Comment: @XaxD . . . This query returns *all* months in the `months` table.  If it does not return October, that is because there is no such row in the table.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is `count(*)` as this will count all the rows in the FROM clause no matter if they have values for the left side (pageviews) or not.  So when there is only data for the months side of the join count will return 1 (assuming that every month is in the months tables once).  You need to count something that always exists in the pageviews table rows like pv_date.  When count operates on a column it will not increment if the value for the column is NULL.

Also count(*) will never return NULL as long as there is at least 1 rows in the group so coalesce is unneeded.  This is true for count(pv_date) as long as there are rows in each group and will return 0 if all the values of pv_date in that group are NULL.

If this doesn't correct the issue double check that the source data and the join are operating as expected by removing the count and group by clause and ensure that you are getting the rows for 2020-10-01.

Comment: Replacing `*` with column name did not fix the issue

Comment: There is a row in the months table for 2020-10-01

Comment: Then you my friend are not dealing with the input data you think you are.  Do what I laid out - remove count and group by and look at the data that is coming through from the join.  Is there a 2020-10-01 record? Is there something unexpected?  You are dealing with an issue upstream of count().